# PHP converting hours and minutes into a decimal

Tags: php

I am calculating hours and minutes into variables but i would like to convert this into a decimal number

For example, 1 hour 30 minutes should display as 1.5 and 2 hours 15 minutes would display as 2.25

Comment: This is very simple basic Math, you should be able to do that yourself.

Comment: 60(Min in 1 hour) + 30 = 90. Then 90 / 60 = 1.5

Comment: Is this meant to be sarcastic @HankyPanky? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function convert($hours, $minutes) {
    return $hours + round($minutes / 60, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$hrs = "2:15:0";
$decimalHours = decimal($hrs);

function decimal($time)
{
    $hms = explode(":", $time);
    return ($hms[0] + ($hms[1]/60) + ($hms[2]/3600));
}

echo $decimalHours;
```

Try this code

Answer (score 2):

This is so easy. Divide by 60.

```
function convertMinutesToDecimal($minutes)
{
    return $minutes / 60;
}

echo '15 mins is '.convertMinutesToDecimal(15)."\n";
echo '30 mins is '.convertMinutesToDecimal(30)."\n";
echo '45 mins is '.convertMinutesToDecimal(45)."\n";
```

Output:

```
15 mins is 0.25 
30 mins is 0.5 
45 mins is 0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function time_to_float($time) {
    $timeArr = explode(":", $time);
    return $timeArr[0] + ($timeArr[1] / 60);
}

$time_str = "1:30";

$formatted = sprintf("%0.2f", time_to_float($time_str));

echo $formatted; // 1.50
```